# Having QStandardItem as child of multiple parent Items

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qstandarditem

Is it possible to display/have a single QStandardItem be a child of multiple parents at the same time?

I have a situation in which I have a primary list of objects and then several sublists of those objects.

For example:

```
List [Parent 1]:
    Child 1
    Child 2
    Child 3
SubList [Parent 2]:
    Child 1
    Child 2
SubList [Parent 3]:
    Child 2
    Child 3
```

I have not used Qt's Model/View system before but I am trying to see if it would be feasible for this project.

I currently have a set of multiple lists. When I want to add a item to these lists I pass a pointer to the ListItem and store that in a vector. So by updating an item in one of the lists, all of the lists reflect the change.

It is possible that this may not be a time when the Model/View is practical, or that I would have to do some major restructuring to make it work, but as I have it now it would be easiest if I was able to have multiple parents reflect the same child.

The only solution I have been able to come up with so far would be to have seperate QStandardItem's as each child, but pass them a pointer so I can connect an signal for when the ListItem is updated, and then update the information in the QStandarItem accordingly.

If there is a better way to go about this I am all ears.

Comment: No, it is not possible. You may design your own child of `QStandardItem` which instances will refer to same data source. Why do you want to use same item with different parents? It is not necessary in any cases.

Comment: So the situation that I described above where there are multiple lists that contain various overlapping subsets of the same data objects.

Normally you just set it and leave be but I was hoping to be able to have them automatically update when either of the spots is edited.

In the situation above, I wanted child 2 of parent 3 to update when child 2 of parent 2 is edited

Comment: You may create a collection of `QStandardItem`'s that will represent your one logical item. And update whole of them, when necessary.